# How to programmatically use the "between" operator in Drupal Views

Tags: views

I have a price field and I want to see if the value of this field is between multiple price segments.

E.g.: `(price BETWEEN 0 AND 100) OR (price BETWEEN 150 AND 200)`

So how can I use the "between" operator in Drupal Views to programmatically alter a query?

Comment: You can set OR in views filter.

Comment: @SumitMadan I am manipulating the query manually and I have no filters or contextual filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
$where = array(
    'conditions' => array(
         array(
              'field' => $field,
              'value' => array(0, 100),
              'operator' => 'BETWEEN',
         ),
         array(
              'field' => $field,
              'value' => array(150, 200),
              'operator' => 'BETWEEN',
         ),
    ),
    'args' => array(),
    'type' => 'OR',
);
$query->where[] = $where;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7). So see the [example](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where/7) to add `OR` in condition. Check out code :

```
$this->query->add_where(
  $this->options['group'],
    db_or()
      ->condition($field, array(0, 100), 'BETWEEN')
      ->condition($field, array(150, 200), 'BETWEEN')
  );
```

Comment: Yes, I am using hook_views_query_alter. But what does `$this` stand for?

Comment: `$this->query` is equals to `$query`.

Comment: And $this->options?

Comment: That can be null I think.

Comment: For whatever reason it does not work..